# A zeta function using half of the primes

Tags: cv.complex-variables

It is well known that the *zeta function* satisfies the *Euler product formula*. See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula).

Enumerate all primes by $p_1, p_2, \ldots $ in ascending order.
Set $S$ to be the set of all $p_i$ where $i$ is odd. If, for $s > 1$, you define
$$\zeta_0(s) = \prod_{p \in S} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}},$$ is it true that $(\zeta_0(s))^2$ has a meromorphic continuation to the entire complex plane?

Comment: Every other prime seems to be an arbitrary choice. In my opinion, a more interesting question borne of the same motivation would be: for which subsets $S$ of the primes does the corresponding Euler product admit an analytic continuation?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95205/a-question-about-partial-euler-products, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70318/euler-product-over-primes-congruent-to-3-mod-4, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28000/what-are-the-analytic-properties-of-dirichlet-euler-products-restricted-to-arithm, not that they answer your specific question, but maybe a good place to look...

Comment: Thank you. I wrote this specific question because it is appearing in my work. I agree that the more general question is also interesting.